# Telegram Bot | How to handle multiple user at the same time?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot that can get data about cyrpto currencies. The bot work with no errors but it can handle just one user at the same time. If two users send request at the same time the bot get the data for who send request earlier than rerun for the other user and get data. this causes so much delay. How can I handle it?

Comment: Please specify which version of the `python-telegram-bot` library you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to create some kind of queue object where requests can live & get handled in a first-in-first-out fashion. The [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) modules might help with this.